# How can I rate limit my AJAX upload requests while also giving it multiple file support?

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I have created an upload script to upload files to my server.

I need to support multiple file uploads, as well as chunking as files can range from 5Mb to 2Gb.

The issue I'm currently having is once I start the upload, all the chunks on all the files are started at once, and this locks up the browser as I know on chrome you can only make up to 6 requests per domain.

Here is the javascript code.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  var status = document.getElementById('status'),
  uploaders = [],
  upload,
  chooseFile;

  upload = function (blobOrFile, chunk_num, chunk_total, file_name) {
    var uXHR;

    uXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    uXHR.open('POST', '/upload/url/', true);
    uXHR.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
      if (e.lengthComputable) {
        console.log(Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100));
      }
    };
    uXHR.onloadend = function (e) {
      uploaders.pop();
      if (!uploaders.length) {
        status.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' All Done! '));

        allFilesUploaded(file_name, chunk_total);
      }
    };
    uploaders.push(uXHR);
    uXHR.send(blobOrFile);
  };

  chooseFile = document.getElementById('file-input');
  chooseFile.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var self = e.currentTarget;
    var a;
    for ( a=0; a<self.files.length; a++ ) {
      var blob = self.files[a],
      bytes_per_chunk,
      SIZE,
      num_chunks,
      start,
      end,
      fileName;

      fileName = self.files[a].name;
      bytes_per_chunk = parseInt(67108864, 10); // 64mb
      SIZE = blob.size;
      num_chunks = Math.max(Math.ceil(SIZE / bytes_per_chunk), 1);
      console.log('Sending' + num_chunks );
      start = 0;
      end = bytes_per_chunk;
      var i = 1;
      while (start < SIZE) {
        upload(blob.slice(start, end), i, num_chunks, fileName);
        start = end;
        end = start + bytes_per_chunk;
        i++;
      }
    }
  }, false);
})();
```

And the basic html.

```
<input type="file" id="file-input" multiple="multiple" />
<p id="status"></p>
```

I would like to create a queue of chunks to be uploaded and then have up to 6 running at a time.

Also have a callback when each file is finished uploading and a global percentage would be good, but I'm not sure how to implement this, as I can only seem to work it out for the chunks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at [dropszone js](http://www.dropzonejs.com). Its very good for doing exactly what your looking to do and provides a very good interface too. It has options to configure how many concurrent uploads and gives you a good API to handle failures etc

Comment: I have tired quite a few different uploading scripts/libraries, but I always seem to run into issues with compatibility, and then not not everything working as required. I only have a small set of devices for this to work on as it is for a backend system.

Comment: I've found dropzone documentation to be really good and gives good example code. Even provides a php script for handling the file saving on the server. Without it, you would need to build and array to store the queue, and when downloads finish start uploading the next file etc. You would also need to factor in failed uploads and how to recover.

Comment: I have had a look at dropzone, it doesn't support chunked uploads, which I require as most files are at least 100Mb or more in size.